# table inner join not displaying expected results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get a query to display some results. I double checked the logic to make sure that it is correct and it looks like it should work to me but does not.

I created a query with the logic I need to use, code is at the bottom.

```
SELECT * FROM vendor v
-- select table
inner join product p
-- join second table
on v.V_CODE = p.V_CODE
-- link table
where p.P_QOH <= p.P_MIN;
-- filter products where product quantity on hand is less than or equal to product minimum count

-- TODO: Get results to actually display
```

Expected results are: a list of products where the product quantity on hand
is less than or equal to the minimum quantity.

Actual results: No products return, its empty.

This is what my table looks like: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEaCV.png)

Comment: If are you asking how how to run the query? Ctrl + Shift + Enter, if you are asking why the result is empty, then please show your table structure... and a sample data that you are using.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini added image of the table

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see on your table, the condition is never met. Also it might be a performance issue if the table became very large and should be a
self-join.

Comment: The performance is no problem as the table has a rather limited number of entries. I did reverse the logic and found out that you are correct. The condition is never met and because there is no list of expected return for me to look up I cant tell if the code is wrong or if simply everything is working correctly and the case itself is wrong.

I'm siding with the case that the code is correct and showing the correct results, its just that there are no results that return true.